# Combine multiple sphinx documentations with autoclass from several projects

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Haven't found detailed information according how to correctly use intersphinx.
I want to combine multiple sphinx documentations which are in different projects (API backends),
my structure is:

```
Projects
├── main_api_name
│   └── docs
│      └── source
│          └── ...
│          └── index.rst
│          └── main_api_name.rst
│      └── build
│   └── lib
│      └── <python files>
├── api_name1
│   └── docs
│      └── source
│          └── ...
│          └── index.rst
│          └── api_name1.rst
│      └── build
│   └── lib
│      └── <python files>
├──
```

All sphinx documentation (whether generated or not) of all projects in `Projects` dir I want to store in `main_api_name` project.
My index.rst in projects same as:

```
###########################################
Main API documentation
###########################################


********
Contents
********

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   main_api_name
```

main_api_name.rst and api_name1 and others look like:

```
<main_api_name>
=============================================

Access actions
##############
.. autoclass:: lib.api_access_actions.API
   :members:

Access profiles
###############
.. autoclass:: lib.api_access_profiles.API
   :members:
...
```

Summarizing all of above: I just want to combine them in one sphinx documentation

Comment: This cannot be done via intersphinx. You will need to combine all the project docs into a single project.

Comment: @StevePiercy do you mean combine all projects python stuff, configure global index.rst in them, so that it will contain all project docs and then run sphinx-build (make html) in order to generate projects docs? or you mean generate projects docs one by one and combine them?

Comment: I mean the former.